# Rasterization tools for vector datasets with styles

Tags: arcgis-desktop, style, rasterization, personal-geodatabase

I have hundreds of Personal Geodatabases and I want to create one georeferenced TIFF for each one. Each PGDB has the same feature classes ('CotourLines', 'Hidrography', etc) for what I have some layers with the styles. The style (or symbol) for each feature could depend on many fields. And the final TIFF files must have a fixed pixel size.

I was searching for tools I can use. From ArcToolBox there are some tools like 'Feature to Raster' but doesn't fit to my requirements.

Maybe should I make an automation?

Having an MXD containing the layers with the styles, loading the feature classes of each PGDB, and using 'Export Map' to create the TIFF file?

This is the only solution I have in mind.

I think there should be an straightforward solution I could use, maybe with an ArcGis extension. I could export the PGDB to ShapeFiles (or a PostGIS database) and have the styles in SLD files.

Comment: If you were to focus the post toward a question, this could be a really good question.